# python convert list [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] to [0, 1, 2], [1,2,3], [2,3,4]

Tags: python, list

I could implement this use like this `[a[i:i+3], for i in range()]`.
But I found when a is large, it costs too many cpu resources, how could I solve this bottleneck?

Comment: what exactly your list will be? only integer or combination of string? for optimal help please specify what are possible list elements.

Comment: I got two types of list. Integers and list of floats.

Comment: You may want to back up and describe the context of the larger problem you're trying to solve with these lists; maybe we can offer a suggestion that doesn't require constructing that large data structure at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your list has the size of `n` you'll have O(n) such lists to compose - there's no way around it.

One thing that you can do though, is calculate it lazily, this way the next list will be computed only when you try to access it. Using a generator for this example is pretty straightforward:

```
def compose_lists(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)-2):
        yield lst[i:i+3]
```

Comment: Couldn't you have just changed `[...]` to `(...)` to convert the code from the question into a generator, instead of totally rewriting it?

Comment: This is exactly what I miss!